# Recent upgrade to 2.25.0 - the OpenLayers map preview not working anymore

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, wms, error

Recently we upgraded GeoServer from the stable release Dec 2023 (forgot the number) where everything was working fine to the March 19 stable release. The trouble is the OpenLayers preview shows just "white"

For the record - we also tried this on a plain new installation without any merging and the same.

in the log there's a bunch of errors:

> Request: getServiceInfo 24 Mar 06:22:54 ERROR  [geoserver.ows] -
> java.lang.IllegalAccessError: superclass access check failed: class
> org.marlin.pisces.MarlinRenderingEngine (in unnamed module
> @0x1c030759) cannot access class sun.java2d.pipe.RenderingEngine (in
> module java.desktop) because module java.desktop does not export
> sun.java2d.pipe to unnamed module @0x1c030759
>
> Request: getServiceInfo 24 Mar 06:23:11 ERROR  [geoserver.ows] -
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class
> sun.java2d.SurfaceData    at
> java.desktop/sun.java2d.SunGraphicsEnvironment.createGraphics(SunGraphicsEnvironment.java:132)
> at
> java.desktop/sun.java2d.HeadlessGraphicsEnvironment.createGraphics(HeadlessGraphicsEnvironment.java:73)
> at
> java.desktop/java.awt.image.BufferedImage.createGraphics(BufferedImage.java:1183)
>
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840) Caused by:
> java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: Exception
> java.lang.IllegalAccessError: superclass access check failed: class
> org.marlin.pisces.MarlinRenderingEngine (in unnamed module
> @0x1c030759) cannot access class sun.java2d.pipe.RenderingEngine (in
> module java.desktop) because module java.desktop does not export
> sun.java2d.pipe to unnamed module @0x1c030759 [in thread
> "qtp410495873-21"]    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native
> Method)
>
> 24 Mar 06:23:30 ERROR  [geoserver.ows] -
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class
> sun.java2d.SurfaceData    at
> java.desktop/sun.java2d.SunGraphicsEnvironment.createGraphics(SunGraphicsEnvironment.java:132)
> at
> java.desktop/sun.java2d.HeadlessGraphicsEnvironment.createGraphics(HeadlessGraphicsEnvironment.java:73)
> at
> java.desktop/java.awt.image.BufferedImage.createGraphics(BufferedImage.java:1183)

Do you have any thoughts about what went wrong during the upgrade or even the total new installation?

Did a complete fresh install on a VM and exactly the same.. again on the previous stable release had no problems, worked right out of the box.

Comment: You need to read the upgrade notes and delete the marlin jar from your lib folder if you use java 17 plus

Comment: thank you so much!